# TypeError for jquery validation script

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I want to try some simple example with jquery validate plugin in mvc application.
I have a JS module with this method:

```
ValidateRestriction: function (element) {
    var inputs = $('form').validator();
    inputs.data("validator").checkValidity();

    $(element).validate({
        rules :{
            field: {
                number: true,
                "min": "1",
                "max": "Infinity"
            },
            ignore: ".ignore",
        onkeyup: false
    }
    });
}
```

But in console I get an error:

> TypeError: $(...).validator is not a function
>   var inputs => $('form').validator();

In firebug I see that all needed JS functions are loaded. Verified in console:

```
>>> $.fn.validate
function()
```

What's the problem with this?

Comment: Just like your error message is trying to tell you, there is no such thing as `.validator()` in this plugin.  Same goes for `.checkValidity()`... no such method.  Where did you get this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
ValidateRestriction: function (element) {
            var inputs = $('form').validator();                   
            inputs.data("validator").checkValidity();

            $(element).validate({
                rules :{
                    field: {
                        number: true,
                        "min": "1",
                        "max": "Infinity"
                    },
                    ignore: ".ignore",
                onkeyup: false
            }
            });

        }
```

These are your issues...

1)  No such things as `validator()` and `checkValidity()` in the jQuery Validate plugin.

2)  You cannot attach `.validate()` to an input element, assuming that's what your `element` argument is supposed to be.  The `.validate()` method only gets attached to the `form`.

3)  Your `onkeyup` and `ignore` options are placed improperly.  These are siblings of the `rules` option, **not** siblings of `field`.

4)  I have never heard of setting a `max` rule to `"Infinity"`.  If you leave out a `max` rule, the max value can be unlimited, or infinite.

5)  You do not need quotation marks around the method names, nor do you need quotes around a numerical value.

6)  I added the `required` rule for demonstration.  Remove it if you don't want to make the input mandatory.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            field: {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                min: 1
            }
        },
        ignore: ".ignore",
        onkeyup: false
    });

});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/baCBE/**

Answer (score 0):

validator() and checkValidity() are not part of the the jquery validate plugin.  Remove the first two lines then try the simplest possible case to see if your setup is correct

```
$(function(){
 $('form').validate();
})
```

put a class="required" on some elements in your form and test that this is working